# Is it possible in Jade to define and use blocks all in the same template file?

Tags: html, pug

Please, consider the following trivial jade template:

```
form
  block balance
  block address_info
  block additional_info
  block payment_info

block balance
  | a

block address_info
  | b

block additional_info
  | c

block payment_info
  | d
```

First of all, it does not work (otherwise I would not be asking this question).

The produced HTML is simply `<form></form>`.

What I want is to define a layout and then override the layout blocks all in the same template file.
Is it possible?

P.S.
I know I can throw the layout in a different file and then extend it in yet another. However, my layout is specific to just one view, it is a waste to define a separate file for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, what I am looking for is called `mixin`, which are like functions.

So, my trivial example should have been written like so:

```
mixin balance
  | a

mixin address_info
  | b

mixin additional_info
  | c

mixin payment_info
  | d

form
  mixin balance
  mixin address_info
  mixin additional_info
  mixin payment_info
```